# Can be anything done with an empty object?

Tags: php, object

Sry if that question is kind dumb.... But i´ve seen it in our system and i´m curious now...

Can you anything do with an complete empty Object like these(?):

I´ve looked in PHP and searched for but nothing found. Cause it´s obviously, that you can nothin do with an empty Object, right?

```
class Foo {

    function __construct() {

    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
```

I´ve tested like....

```
echo json_encode($foo);
print_r($foo);
var_dump($foo);

{}
Foo Object ( ) 
object(Foo)#428 (0) { }
```

and to set it somehow. But i think the only things, that you can do with it, is to get few useless informations out of it...

Comment: _Can you anything do with an complete empty Object ..._ What do you mean by "do anything"??

Comment: can you fill it  somehow or can it be a usage for something

Comment: `$foo->test = "testing 1.2.3..."; print_r($foo);`

Comment: @woollhaar yes, if you extend the class but it is no use to ask such question. otherwise, it is of no use and also there is no use of extending the class if you do not want to add extra information.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver, so there is an way to fill an empty object :D

Comment: @Wollhaar Yes you could do anything with it, but if this is the only instance where this class appears and no traces of instances are present whatsoever, you better remove it.

Comment: i think it is interesting, that you could fill it almost like an array. And maybe, they would be some performance problems in higher use. But i think it´s good to now, that you can more do with an object, than "just" use the given variables and functions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very similar to using [stdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php).  You can add/change/retrieve etc.

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->test = "This is a test";
$foo->myarray[] = "First array element";
$foo->obj = new Foo;
$foo->obj->new_test = "New test";

var_dump($foo);
```

Yields:

```
object(Foo)#1 (3) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(14) "This is a test"
  ["myarray"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "First array element"
  }
  ["obj"]=>
  object(Foo)#2 (1) {
    ["new_test"]=>
    string(8) "New test"
  }
}
```